# how to show labels on Pie chart using DevExpress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devexpress

I'm using a DevExpress chart to show my piechart. I have the legends, and I'm trying to display the labels on every section of the pie.
below is my code:
I couldn't find it anywhere in the source to showcase labels. Is there any other lib or component to use in order to show labels?

```
import {
  Chart,
  PieSeries,
  Title,
  Legend
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui';

const PieChart = ({ chartData }) => {
  return (
    <Chart
          data={data}
        >
          <PieSeries
            valueField="area"
            argumentField="country"
          />
          <Title
            text="Area of Countries"
          />
         
          <Legend />
        </Chart>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MUI X Charts (by MUI, the same organization behind Material UI):

```js
import { PieChart, pieArcLabelClasses  } from '@mui/x-charts/PieChart';

const dataPie = [
  { label: 'High', value: 400, color:"#E55353" },
  { label: 'Medium', value: 300, color:"#F9B115" },
  { label: 'Low', value: 300, color:"#3399FF" },
  { label: 'Info', value: 200, color:"#2EB85C" },
];

const TOTAL = dataPie.map((item) => item.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const getArcLabel = (params) => {
  const percent = params.value / TOTAL;
  return `${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`;
};
```

```
 <PieChart
        series={[
          {
      arcLabel:getArcLabel,
      innerRadius: 62,
      outerRadius: 94,
      paddingAngle: 5,
      cornerRadius: 5,
      startAngle: -180,
      endAngle: 180,
      data:dataPie,
      
          },
        ]}
        margin={{ left: 100, top: 30 }}
        width={250}
        height={250}
        legend={{ hidden: true }}
        sx={{
          [`& .${pieArcLabelClasses.root}`]: {
            fill: 'white',
            fontSize: 14,
          },
        }}
      />
```